# how does the chrome calculate the repaint area?

Tags: html, google-chrome, webkit

the chrome dev tools now support to show paint rectangles,it really helps.but i found some strange thing that sometimes the repaint area is too large to understand.

this is my code

```
<style type="text/css">
    div { width:500px; height:30px; border:1px solid red; margin:20px;}
    div.inner { width:400px; height:20px; border:1px solid green; margin:5px;}
</style>
<div id="txt"></div>
<div></div>
<div>
    <div class="inner">

        <script> document.write(111);</script>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://chillrain.com/api/sleep.php?time=9"></script>
<div>
    <div class="inner">

        <script> document.write(222);</script>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://chillrain.com/api/sleep.php?time=10"></script>
<div>
    <div class="inner">

        <script> document.write(333);</script>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="http://chillrain.com/api/sleep.php?time=11"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
    <script> setTimeout( function(){ 
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = "Hello World!"
} ,1000);
</script>
```

notice:sleep.php will sleep seconds and then return nothing, using it to block the page's rendering.

the first step,seems ok,it paints the whole page

[image]

the second step,donot u think the repaint area is too large?
[image]

the third step,too large ...
[image]

the fourth step, seems okay , it repaint the whole page again.
the fifth step,seems okay, it only repaint the 'txt' div
[image]

why the second and the third steps repaint so large area?